# missing feature in lucene 4.0 snapshot

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to use lucene 4.0 snapshot version, however StandardAnalyzer is missing in this version :(. Anybody knows on how to replace this?

In the sample code given in the [Lucene Summary](http://search-lucene.com/jd/lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html)

the StandardAnalyzer is used, but no where to be found..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the StandardAnalyzer was moved  under org.apache.lucene.modules.analysis.standard.*
You can find the StandardAnalyzer in the 
[SVN Trunk](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/modules/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/)

The reason is [here](http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2010/04/lucene-and-solr-development-merged.html)

Comment: there is no such a org.apache.lucene.modules.analysis.standard.* package in my lucene-core.snapshot??

Comment: do you have lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-*.jar? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadluceneanalyzerscommon4020110114080549jar.htm

Comment: ah ok, so I should download this jar and use it as a seperate jar together with the lucene-core? In version 3.0.2 everything was in one jar..

Comment: yes, you should download lucene-analyzers-common-4.0-*.jar and add to the classpath of your application.
if you are using maven:
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.lucene -DartifactId=lucene-analyzers-common -Dversion=4.0 -Dfile=lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did that and it worked!
But now, I'm facing problems in the indexer. Namely this doesn't work: `IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(25000));`, can you tell me something about it? Yeah, its seems a complete mess now, changing the version of lucene..

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-BETA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.0, I see it here:
lucene-4.0.0\analysis\common\src\java\org\apache\lucene\analysis\standard
In eclipse, create a separate project for analysis, and include in its build path the core project. You will find some red marks because of some foreign characters in foreign language packages, I have ignored them for now because I only wanted standard analyzer. Hope this helps and saves you a lot of man hours and some frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You have found standard analyzer in andriy 's answer..and for indexwriter the syntax is different in lucene 4.0..you can get the idea from the link:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles.html