# Lucene 4.0 overrides final method tokenStream

Tags: java, lucene

For different reasons I have to work with the latest release of Lucene's API.

The API isn't well documented yet so I find myself not able to perform a simple `addDocument()`

Here is the `Writer` initialization:

```
analyzer = new StopAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);
writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File(ConfigUtil.getProperty("lucene.directory"))), config);
```

The simple `toDocument` method:

```
public static Document getDocument(User user) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    FieldType storedType = new FieldType();
    storedType.setStored(true);
    storedType.setTokenized(false);

    // Store user data
    doc.add(new Field(USER_ID, user.getId().toString(), storedType));
    doc.add(new Field(USER_NAME, user.getFirstName() + user.getLastName(), storedType));

    FieldType unstoredType = new FieldType();
    unstoredType.setStored(false);
    unstoredType.setTokenized(true);

    // Analyze Location
    String tokens = "";
    if (user.getLocation() != null && ! user.getLocation().isEmpty()){
        for (Tag location : user.getLocation()) tokens += location.getName() + " ";
        doc.add(new Field(USER_LOCATION, tokens, unstoredType));
    }
}
```

When running:

```
Document userDoc = DocumentManager.getDocument(userWrap);
IndexAccess.getWriter().addDocument(userDoc);
```

This is the error message I get:

`class org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ReusableAnalyzerBase overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;`

It may be a simple matter but I cannot find any reference to help with this problem. I'm using a default `analyzer` and I followed a tutorial in order to avoid the deprecated `Field.Index.ANALYZED`

Answer (score 2):

This is due to some kind of JAR version mismatch. You may be depending on a contrib JAR that in turn depends on different version of Lucene. Try to get a hold of the exact dependency set at runtime and look for any version mismatches.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. In the core JAR there is no `Analyzer Class`, therefore I downloaded `lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.jar`. Do you have any idea if this is the official way of doing it?

Comment: It is quite impossible that there is no `Analyzer` in core Lucene since this class is fundamental to the indexing process. I do find it in the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).

Comment: I also find it strange that you use `org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ReusableAnalyzerBase` since this class is not normally found in the ...util package, but in ...analysis. It is also a core class.

Comment: Yes indeed the Analyzer is in the core lib. However (based on previous Lucene releases) I would expect the JAR to also include a `Standard Analyzer`, a `StopAnalyzer` and so on. This was previously discussed on `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604187/missing-feature-in-lucene-4-0-snapshot`. This is how I ended up with those JARs. It is possible that I misunderstood something and that there is a much simpler way to solve all these.

Comment: I still don't see how `ReusableAnalyzerBase` got involved in the story. It doesn't exist in either core or analyzers-common.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18751/discussion-between-ionut-and-marko-topolnik)